# Cant get the location and address of the user

Tags: java, android, mobile, location, getlocation

[So i have that problem that it gives me an error like:

```
error: incompatible types: <anonymous LocationCallback> cannot be converted to PendingIntent
                LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity()).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
```

So how can i get over it ? I want to find the address of the user and update it. I have also fragments that i have to write "this" instead of getActivity() but it gives an error each way.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eynPO.png)

Comment: can you add code snippet here rather than image

Comment: I wanted to show you the underlined parts sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the photo attached the error is shown because you have not rewritten the code completely you are missing the 3rd parameter `looper`

your code should be something like

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        //All your code for parsing or extracting data
                    }
                },
                Looper.myLooper());
```